# Up Button in Toolbar doesn't do anything

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar

I set up Toolbar in my app (for the first time) but the I can't set the Home (/Up) button to do anything when clicked.
I have 3 activitives (MainActivity , Second , Third) and I've defined the toolbar in all 3 but nothing happens when I click the Home button in each of the activitis I want the button to do his (in my understanding) default action which is go back to the Home Activity which is "MainActivity".

Here is some relevant code:
Toolbar layout (named: app_bar.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/toolBar_background"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:title="@string/app_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my 3 activities layout xmls:
Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
//More layout code...
```

Activity_Second.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Second">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
//More layout code...
```

Activity_Third.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Third">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar"/>
//More layout code
```

Actually all the 3 activities simply include the toolbar layout which names "app_bar.xml".

Here is part of my Mainfest file where I configured the app_parent:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Second"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Second" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Third"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Third" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and ofcourse parts of my java code for each of my 3 activities:
MainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mainBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_main);
        openSecondActivity();
    }
    public void openSecondActivity(){
        mainBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Second");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

SecondActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        btnSecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_second);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        openThirdActivity();
    }

    public void openThirdActivity(){
        btnSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.noamm_000.finaltoolbarproject.Third");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

and ThirdActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_id);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

You can see that all 3 Activities "onCreate" functions are pretty much the same..
When I start my app I can see the toolbar in all 3 activities and I can see the back arrow in all but clicking it do nothing.
I know I can set the `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener` but I just want it to make it default action which is go to home activity....
Thank you very much,
Noam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this...

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked but isn't there exist a defaullt function for this button , one that I dont have to define using the onOptionsItemSelected function?

Comment: @Noam..it's a default function for this button..you have to define it if you want that the Up Button in Toolbar has  to do some your's define specific tasks...

Comment: @Noam My code will take you to the parent activity, rather than just go through the back stack. I've also added the Intent.Flag to clear the back stack, it's a useful one to have when going to a home activity and can stop the back stack getting in a muddle when your users are using the 'Up' button

Comment: @sarurabh gupta I understand what you are saying, it just that I followed the tutorial in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7BWTh6xPsw&list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E&index=38&spfreload=1 
and there he doesn't use the OnOptionsItemSelected method at all but since he is using ActionBar and not toolbar maybe it is different , I dont know , I will stick to what you and others answered me here anyway. once again thank you.

Comment: @Noam..yes may be this can be the difference...and yes! if my answer help you then just please mark as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
               //finish(); or Do wahtever you wnat to do
                return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp)

Comment: Thank you , it worked but isn't there exist a defaullt function for this button , one that I dont have to define using the onOptionsItemSelected function?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having parent activity,Follow this code,

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)== null) {
                onBackPressed();
            }else{
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked but isn't there exist a defaullt function for this button , one that I dont have to define using the onOptionsItemSelected function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activities

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemIdSelected(int id) {   
    switch (id) {
            case R.id.home:
                //do stuff 
                break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your case, I recommend to you create a AbstractActivity which inherit all your activities. So you can factor a number of behavior , including management of the toolbar button

Comment: it should be Android.R.id.home (without the adnroid word - nothing happens) and it worked but isn't there exist a defaullt function for this button , one that I dont have to define using the onOptionsItemSelected function? and about your recommandation - sounds good , will try

Comment: This is the default function for the whole ToolbarButton :)